# ui-router - How can I insert a view inside a view in a state?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have another problem with my views. I would like to have a view in a state and views in that.  Here's what I have:

```
var home = {
    name: 'home',
    url: '/home/'
};

var homeAccess = {
    name: 'home.access',
    url: 'access',
    views: {
       'home@': {
           templateUrl: 'app/access/partials/webapi.html'
       },
       'home@abc': {
           templateUrl: 'app/access/partials/webapi2.html'
       }
       'home@def': {
           templateUrl: 'app/access/partials/webapi2.html'
       }
    }
};
```

In my webapi.html I have this code:

```
  <div ui-view="abc"></div>
  <div ui-view="def"></div>
```

What happens is that the webapi.html appears but the views abc and def are not populated. Also is this even a valid way to code this or should I better be using ng-include for those two inner views?

Here is a plunker that I think demonstrates the problem:

http://plnkr.co/edit/Dive7GO1xyPjcNr2ZMGl?p=preview

What I want to see is "abc template" but what I see is "ABC"

```
        views: {
            "viewA": {
                template: "<div ui-view='abc'>ABC</div>"
            },
            "viewA@abc": {
                template: "abc template"
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I update your plunker, is that what you trying to do?

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/RV2VdcMv2vuHjM4Khyks?p=preview)

```
  <div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
      <a class="brand" ui-sref="index">Quick Start</a>
      <ul class="nav">
        <li><a ui-sref="index">Home</a></li>
        <li><a ui-sref="route1.abc">Route 1</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

$stateProvider
        .state('route1', {
            url: "/route",
            views: {
                "viewA": {
                    template: "<div ui-view='abc'>ABC</div>"
                },
                "viewB": {
                  template: "ViewB"
                }
            }
        })
        .state('route1.abc',{
          url: "/abc",
          views: {
            "abc": {
              template: "abc template"
            }
          }
        })
    });
```

Comment: I forgot to change the url to  route1.abc

Answer (score 0):

Needs to be {{view}}@{{state}}. Since your state is route1, your view becomes abc@route1.

```
views: {
    "viewA": {
        template: "<div ui-view='abc'>ABC</div>"
    },
    "abc@route1": {
        template: "abc template"
    }
}
```